# How to get paypal transaction id from payflow PNREF

Tags: .net, paypal, payflowpro

Payflow sale transaction is returning PNREF something like in this format **BH1P2C012D82**

I want actual TRANSACTION ID something like in this format **4S91519056462460A**

I have used payflow inquiry to fetch transaction details but its response does not contain actual transaction id.

Comment: Is there no `PPREF` (note the double P) in any of your responses?

Comment: yes there is PPREF but its null in the inquiry response

Comment: Maybe in an inquiry, what about in the original TRXTYPE=S that created that PNREF? Is the PPREF there?

Comment: In an original sale transaction, there is no PPREF field, there is only PNREF.

Comment: That's odd--try with the Payflow parameter: `VERBOSITY=HIGH`. If that doesn't work, try with the HTTP request header `PAYPAL-NVP: Y`.  (This is old Payflow lore, I haven't implemented that gateway in 5+ years)

Comment: tried both but no luck.

Comment: Is this the same account as BH1P2C012D82, or a different Payflow gateway account? In manager.paypal.com , do all the processors show as "PayPal" , or something else? (FDMS comes to mind as one of the test account defaults)

Comment: there is only one processor and that is Paypal, i am using sandbox this might be the reason that ppref is null?